# Generating clean Url Slugs via routes in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, webforms

I can generate good url rewriting in IIS but the client controls the production IIS server and I can't touch it. Also having some issues with the url rewriting in web.config as it doesn't recognize the namespace. I want to turn this:

```
https://www.website.com/index.aspx?qs=a-page
```

into

```
https://www.website.com/a-page
```

Can I do this in code somewhere within the web froms framework?

Comment: Did you try googling for "ASP.NET route"? A little basic research goes a long ways.

Answer (score 0):

In Gloabal.ascx

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("",
              "a-page", "~/index.aspx?qs=a-page");
    }
```